# remove hidden quotes

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, vbscript, sharepoint-2010

I have a project where I need to receive return equipment based on [tracking] and [serial].  In Sharepoint, we have two List LIST1 and LIST2 that contains the the following: [DateCreated], [Serial], [Username].

The Union between the two lists are working well.

There are other queries that I have created (with relationships) that I believe or feel is probably redundant or non-lightweight.

But ultimately, when I open the receiving log, it doesn't match the last user that the computer was issued to base on: datecreated and Username. Ive used the `MAX()` to fix that problem as I have created a test table with values in it and works.

My guess is that somehow the data in the two lists in SharePoint is adding some problem to the value of the serial number.

What I have done is I copied Union- [Serial] column and pasted into notepad.

The at least 1/4 of the records [serial] has quotations, e.g. "CNU123456", or "5CG123456", or "00123456789012".

I've tried `Replace()` and it never "fixes" the issue.

I've tried `Mid() 1,  -1`  and that seems to fix it but I noticed some inconsistencies and it strips the last value, e.g. before code runs:  "CNU123456". After code runs:  CNU12345

I've tried creating another query to strip the quotes in the `tbl_Receiving`, but results are inconsistent to the theory behind it.

I hope this makes any sense. Im sure you might have to decipher this one.

Is there another way to perform this?

Comment: `Replace(str, """", "")` should remove double quotes from a string. That's about all I can say without seeing your actual code and some sample data.